# Call to super.owner().transfer(msg.value) giving errors

Tags: ethereum, solidity, openzeppelin

I have a contract that inherits from Open Zeppelin's Ownable contract. There is a method payFees() in my contract that is expected to transfer funds to the owner of the contract. The definition of payFees is as follows

```
function payFees() public payable {
        require(students.has(msg.sender), "DOES NOT HAVE STUDENT ROLE");
        if(this.areFeesEnough(msg.value))
        {
            super.owner().transfer(msg.value);
            studentFees[msg.sender] = true;
        }

    }
```

I expect that a call to super.owner() returns the contract owner given that `owner()` is a public view function in the parent `Ownable` contract that returns the owner. Unfortunately, the code fails with the error.

```
             TypeError: Member "transfer" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address.
            super.owner().transfer(msg.value);
```

Any help is appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the `Ownable` contract you're using is similar to https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol, the issue is that `owner()` returns an `address`, but starting in Solidity 0.5, you can only transfer ether to an `address payable`.

You can convert by casting through `uint160` first, something like this:

```
address(uint160(_owner)).transfer(msg.value);
```

Note that you can just use `_owner` directly or just call `owner()`. No need to call `super.owner()` unless you've overridden `owner` in your contract and need to make sure to call the parent contract.

Comment: see: https://cryptozombies.io/en/lesson/4/chapter/2